# Extract JSON object's values as array from MySQL JSON column

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, json-extract

I have a MySQL column of json type.  In there, a dict like JSON object is stored.  Now, I want to extract the values from this JSON object and create a JSON array.

How can I achieve this?

#### Example Query

```
with json_objs(json_col) as (
  select CAST('{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}' AS JSON)
  UNION ALL
  select CAST('{"key3": "value3", "key4": "value4"}' AS JSON)
)
select SOME_EXPR_I_CAN_T_FIGURE_OUT from json_objs
```

#### Expected result

```
+----------------------+
| resulting_column     |
+----------------------+
| ["value1", "value2"] |
| ["value3", "value4"] |
+----------------------+
```

#### (If table DDL is desired:)

```
CREATE TABLE `json_objs` (
  `json_col` json DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Does http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-labs-json-aggregation-functions/ help?

Comment: Are your key names all different or repeating?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `->` operator as in the expression `column -> path` as follows:

```
create table table1 (
   json_dict JSON
);

insert into table1 values('{"ak":"av","bk":"bv"}');
insert into table1 values('{"ak2":"av2","bk2":"bv2"}');

select * from table1;
+------------------------------+
| json_dict                    |
+------------------------------+
| {"ak": "av", "bk": "bv"}     |
| {"ak2": "av2", "bk2": "bv2"} |
+------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select json_dict->"$.*" from table1;
+------------------+
| json_dict->"$.*" |
+------------------+
| ["av", "bv"]     |
| ["av2", "bv2"]   |
+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. also +1 to answer :)

Comment: saved a run around

Answer (score 4):

Other than `->` operator, you can also use the [`Json_Extract()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) function:

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
create table table1 (
   json_dict JSON
);

insert into table1 values('{"ak":"av","bk":"bv"}');
insert into table1 values('{"ak2":"av2","bk2":"bv2"}');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select JSON_EXTRACT(json_dict, '$.*') from table1;

| JSON_EXTRACT(json_dict, '$.*') |
| ------------------------------ |
| ["av", "bv"]                   |
| ["av2", "bv2"]                 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d3B3n2Y3o8saCQVx4DTXmU/0)

Comment: I was faster and you copied code from my answer. However, I upvoted yours because you showed a slightly different alternative :)

Comment: @marekful Thanks for the fiddle. I was lazy to create a fiddle; so pouched on your fiddle :P